# Pass parameter to c# static function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

i'm working in a java script function which bind html.

```
 var mystring = response[i].id;
 var en = "@Gallery.Get.DemoService.Arrange("44")";
```

i want to pass **myString** insted of **44** to **Arrange** function
how can i pass value?

Comment: It's called String concatenation.

Comment: As C# runs on the server and JS on the client, you'll need to send the value to the server for C# to have access to it. You can do that by submitting a form, or making an AJAX request

Comment: @dfsq, Even String concatenation will not work in this scenario